# Rotate specific plots in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am interested in drawing this graph.

[image: Desired output]

This is what I have did so far.

[image: My output]

code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[margin=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}  
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis} [
    no markers,
    axis lines = middle,
    axis line style = {->},
    xlabel = {$y_1$},
    ylabel = {$y_2$},
    xticklabels={,,}
    yticklabels={,,}
    ]          
    \addplot [mark=none, blue]{3*x};
    \addplot [mark=none, blue]{-3*x};
    \node[label={45:{$P_0(0,0)$}},circle,fill,inner sep=1pt] at (axis cs:0,0) {};
    \addplot[domain=-4:4, color=red,samples=2000] {x^2};  %statement 1
    \addplot[domain=-4:4, color=red,samples=2000] {-x^2}; %statement 2
     \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Now I need to rotate the plot marked as statement 1 and statement 2 in the code.

I have tried using

```
\addplot[domain=-10:10, color=blue,samples=2000,
     transform canvas={rotate around={90:(0,0)}}]{x^2};
```

but I'm getting some absurd outputs. 
I'm pretty much experienced in LaTeX math, but I'm new to TikZ and PGF.

Comment: please make your example fully compilable.

Comment: Yes. Check it now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can still use `rotate around`

```
\documentclass[border = 5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [
  no markers,
  axis lines = middle,
  axis line style = {->},
  xlabel = {$y_1$},
  ylabel = {$y_2$},
  xticklabels={,,}
  yticklabels={,,},
  % added this
  anchor=origin,
  ]          
  \addplot [mark=none, blue]{3*x};
  \addplot [mark=none, blue]{-3*x};
  \node[label={45:{$P_0(0,0)$}},circle,fill,inner sep=1pt] at (axis cs:0,0) {};
  \end{axis}

  \begin{axis} [ % added this
    rotate around={-45:(current axis.origin)},
    anchor=origin,
    hide axis,
    ]
    \addplot[domain=-4:4, color=red,samples=200] {x^2};  %statement 1
    \addplot[domain=-4:4, color=red,samples=200] {-x^2}; %statement 2  
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]